# What are these paint patches on this 787-8?

Tags: wing, feature-identification, boeing-787, paint

What are these paint patches on this British Airways 787-8 (G-ZBJB)?
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are fixed spots where the surface paint has peeled off. Both Boeing and Airbus have been having this issue with their newer models.

Manufacturers are stressing that this is simply a cosmetic nuissance:

https://mentourpilot.com/is-boeing-also-dealing-with-peeling-paint-issues/

Comment: One of the major causes of that kind of pain adhesion is mechanics touching the structure with silicone grease residues on their hands.  Extremely difficult to remove.

Comment: "Pain adhesion"; sounds about right ;)

Comment: As an airline (paying customer) I would also got mad about this. A cosmetic nuisance is if the color becomes matte of timer, not peeling off.

Comment: Agreed 100% Ratrod look don't suit airliners...

Comment: Sounds like Boeing and Airbus have decided to switch paint suppliers to whomever GM has been using for the last couple of decades.